# Error import python-pushover

Tags: python, python-2.7, push-notification

I am currently running python 2.7.

I already installed python-pushover.

But when I try to import following code

```
from pushover import init, Client'
```

I get following error

```
from pushover import init, Client
ImportError: cannot import name init
```

I have tried

```
import pushover
from pushover import init, Client
```

same error.

Comment: How did you install it.

Comment: I did pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: Forgot to add this.                                                                          python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-pushover==0.2
requests==2.10.0
selenium==2.48.0
virtualenv==15.0.2

Comment: According to this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pushover/ your code is correct.                                                                         It seems that the python version which imports `pushover` is different from the python version where `pushover` is installed .

Comment: I am not sure what could be wrong. I have python 2.7. I manually went into python2.7 folder, dragged pip.exe to install requirements.txt. It seem like it installed pushover but can't import init and client.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you did `pip install pushover`. However, this will install a [different package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pushover) from [the one you are interested in](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pushover). Instead, you will need to uninstall that package:

```
pip uninstall pushover
```

and install the correct package:

```
pip install python-pushover
```

Once you do that, your code should work as expected.

Comment: Hello, I tried that but still getting some error. Weird thing is that it is working fine on my mac. But only getting error on my linux ubuntu and window.  I did both pip2.7 install and pip install.

Comment: Does it raise an exception when you do just `import pushover`? If you did do `pip install pushover` at any time in the process, it is possible that Python is still accessing that version instead of `python-pushover`.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  mine stopped working with the same error after upgrade to Catalina, now I cannot get pushover working again.